# IS the use of SVG as Embedded code a safety concern

Tags: svg

After some online checks, it seems that using SVG images is not safe.

But instead of placing it as an image, is it safe to copy the code and paste it directly in the web page?
Usage is basicaly for animations. No Javascript.

Comment: Why do you think using SVG in an image context is not safe? If you control the image or web page it's as safe as you make it.

Comment: I read some articles about security issues with SVG files.
By your answer, do I understand that if I make my own SVG in Illustrator, there is no security issues? Compared to an SVG file I would get online.

Comment: Well if you wrote it you know what's in it and what it does, no?